# Android Studio: I am trying to wire a button to a toast but there is an error with the callback method

Tags: android, button, toast, android-toast

```
package com.example.chris.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        public void buttonWasClicked(View button) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

//The buttonWasClicked is not red but greyed out in the editor, and the editor shows an error that buttonWasClicked has not been used before. I'm not sure why, I thought this was how I define a callback method.

Comment: No reason for downvoting, or if there is a reason, should be posted here to improve user knowledge about this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is inside the `onCreate()` method, that's why. Move it outside `onCreate()` to be able to call it.

Try this:

```
package com.example.chris.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                buttonWasClicked(view);
            }
        });
    }
    public void buttonWasClicked(View button) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this helped you, please mark it as the correct answer! thanks and good luck!